# Tracking finances owed using a database

Tags: hsqldb, libreoffice-base

For years, I have used the humble spreadsheet as a way of keeping track of finances, but as this spreadsheet grew in size, and as I required more types of data analyses, it eventually became clear that a spreadsheet was no longer going to cut it. Problem is, going from Calc to Base has been a slow learning process in understanding SQL (HSQLDB, specifically), particularly its syntax.

Below is an example table with some arbitrary values. We'll call it `Table A`. There are a lot of other columns in my original table, but are either irrelevant, or I have already figured out what to do with them.

| Quantity | Account Paid From | Recipient A Percentage | Recipient B Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 100 | 0 |
| 200 | B | 0 | 100 |
| 500 | A | 0 | 100 |
| 50 | B | 100 | 0 |
| 10 | A | 40 | 60 |

The idea here is that in row 1, Person A paid for something intended solely for person A. Therefore, this transaction does not result in anyone owing anything to another person. Same with row 2, where person B paid for something intended solely for person B

In row 3, person A paid $500 on behalf of person B. Person B now owes Person A $500.

In row 4, B Paid $50 for A. Subtract 50 from 500, and B now only owes A $450

In row 5, A paid for something that is 40% theirs, and 60% for B. In other words, A paid $6 out of the $10 for B. B now owes A `500 - 50 + 6` $456

I'm looking for something along the lines of the following:

1. Select all entries where `Account Paid From` = A
2. Of those entries, take the total sum of `Quantity` * `Recipient B Percentage` / 100
3. The result is how much B owes A
4. Select all entries where `Account Paid From` = B
5. Of those entries, take the total sum of `Quantity` * `Recipient A Percentage` / 100
6. The result is how much A owes B
7. Subtract `A owes B` from `B owes A` to find out who is in debt to the other (if the value is + or -), and by how much.

I guess something along the lines of:

```
SELECT SUM("Account Paid From" * "Recipient B Percentage / 100) 
WHERE "Account Paid From" = "A" - SUM("Account Paid From" * "Recipient B Percentage / 100) 
WHERE "Account Paid From" = "B" AS "Owed" 
FROM "Table A"
```

But...you know, without syntax errors screaming at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I will use table name "T" and the following abbreviated column names:

"Quantity" "Q", "Account Paid From" "APF", "Recipient A Percentage" "RAP", "Recipient B Percentage" "RBP"

1. SELECT * FROM T WHERE "APF" = 'A'
2. SELECT SUM("Q" * "RBP" / 100) AS "Sum RBP" FROM "T" WHERE "APF" = 'A'
3. 
4. 
5. SELECT SUM("Q" * "RAP" / 100) AS "Sum RAP" FROM "T" WHERE "APF" = 'B'
6. 
7. SELECT "Sum RBP" - "Sum RAP" FROM (SELECT SUM("Q" * "RBP" / 100) AS "Sum RBP" FROM "T" WHERE "APF" = 'A'), (SELECT SUM("Q" * "RAP" / 100) AS "Sum RAP" FROM "T" WHERE "APF" = 'B')

Comment: Perfect. I just had to modify `WHERE "APF" = 'B'` to WHERE "APF" = 'B1' OR "APF" = 'B2'` to adapt it to my needs, but that was everything I needed to figure the rest out. Cheers.